Doesn't the Aswamedha sacrifice debunk Vedic Hinduism completely and show that the rishis and Vedas were not divine?
Aswamedha sacrifice is an important sacrifice. It was done by Dasaratha, by Rama in Uttara Kanda, by Yudhisthira on recommendation of Krishna, by Indra, and by several kings.
And in that, there is indisputable evidence that bestiality did happen - that the queen actually took the dead horse's genitals into her own genital. The Tattiriya Samhita, the Satapatha Brahmana heavily indicate that and Apastambha and Baudhyana Srauta Sutra confirms it (Ap 20.18.4

After (the Adhvaryu) has connected her genital organ with the genital organ (of the horse) with utsakthyor grdam dhehi...,' the chief queen censures the horse with ambe ambdlyambik...

) There is no translation error in this, everyone can be assured  of it. A Vedic ritual of this stature which tells a Queen to do this cannot be divine, right? It cannot be that a moral God would reveal such verses right? So, the Vedas are not divine and the rishis were probably hallucinating. What counter argument is there?
Note: this post is not about whether Aswamedha sacrifice involves bestiality or not so don't close this please.

You can see proper interpretations of different Acharyas for this here.

Debunk?? No.
Assuming the rituals do prescribe bestiality, the debunking logic still doesn't work.


Premise A


A Vedic ritual of this stature which tells a Queen to do this cannot
be divine, right?

Why?

Premise B


It cannot be that a moral God would reveal such verses right?

Why?


So, the Vedas are not divine and the rishis were probably
hallucinating. What counter argument is there?

There is no counter argument because there is no argument from your side. You are just expressing your opinions and prejudices as accepted objective truths.
It's like some one saying Buddhism cannot be a true religion, as it starts with the letter B. How can a true religion start with the letter B, right??
Your argument is similarly ridiculous, because you have not established the premises, you are just asserting them. There are multiple fertility rituals, tantric rituals etc which may seem obscene for today's culture but would have been quite normal in ancient times and therefore inferring their divinity from the view point of today's culture is not a logical argument, it is just an appeal to status quo culture of the times.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
